# svn rollback Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, svn, rollback

I am trying to rollback to a previous version of the file/folder Settings.bundle. A file was added to Settings.bundle/en.lproj. If I just delete it I just keep getting missing file warnings (and I don't want to). So now I am trying to rollback, but it seems to do nothing when I try to run the command:

```
svn merge -r 15:5 ./Settings.bundle/
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work so far according to [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) in svn red book. Maybe it's worth trying to run `svn delete` on those files added since revision 5 (sounds like you don't need them any longer), commit it and perform svn merge again.

Alternatively you can do it manually by running [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.export) of the Settings.bundle to a temp directory. Afterwards `svn delete` on all files added since revision 5 and copy files from temp dir back to your working directory. Now you are ready to commit revision 16.